# Cookie token doesn't match database

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, token

I have a token in my MySQL database on every user. When I login this token will be stored as a cookie, but when I look at the cookie value it doesn't match the one I have in the database.

**An example**

In the database: $6$8J/S65L0$1bQJrlRBYTg6UTvLBKwFwRYzob2kMkv1eFuX693fVWFOiHLo6f7FXLwlo/b6WzDupUW9VrDvpqWk1F/RAncaA.

In the cookie:
%246%248J%2FS65L0%241bQJrlRBYTg6UTvLBKwFwRYzob2kMkv1eFuX693fVWFOiHLo6f7FXLwlo%2Fb6WzDupUW9VrDvpqWk1F%2FRAncaA.

Why is that? I use `setcookie("token", $r['token'], $expire);` to store the token as a cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php.

Edit: The values looks to be the same, just that the value in the cookie is URL encoded

Comment: Before I store the token in the database or in the cookie?

Comment: You could also explain that the data are equal just in another encoding: here url encoding.

Comment: I would probably use it when reading the cookie. I guess you could approach it in different ways though.

Comment: Treps: glad I could help!

Comment: Hmm, one more thing. It works to decode while I'm printing it to the site. But it doesn't work while store it in the cookie. I can use `<pre>` but it looks newbish, or is that the only way?